# Cause of java.io.OptionalDataException in serversocket programming

Tags: java, sockets, stream

I am writing a serversocket program, and i am trying to pass objects (in this case: ParticipantWorkState) into ObjectOutputStream and read it via an ObjectInputStream. The ParticipantWorkState class implements Serializable.

When I try to gather the objects from all the connected clients, it throws the java.io.OptionalDataException exception. What am I doing wrong?

I am receiving the objects like this:

```
private ArrayList<ConnectionHandler> connections = new ArrayList<>();

public HashMap<Integer, ParticipantWorkState> gatherRequestedWork() {
    broadcast(Protocol.RequestWork);    // Messages the client that they need to send the object
    HashMap<Integer, ParticipantWorkState> pwsList = new HashMap<>();
    
    for (ConnectionHandler c : connections) {
        ParticipantWorkState pws = (ParticipantWorkState) c.receiveObject();
        pwsList.put(c.ID, pws);
    }
    
    return pwsList;
}

public void broadcast(String msg) {
    for (ConnectionHandler ch : connections) {
        ch.sendMessage(msg);
    }
}

[...]

class ConnectionHandler implements Runnable {
    private BufferedReader strIn;
    private PrintWriter strOut;
    private ObjectInputStream objIn;
    private ObjectOutputStream objOut;

    public void run() {
        // I initiate the readers and writers here
        ...
        // Handles other communication
    }

    public void sendMessage(String msg) {
        strOut.println(msg); 
    }

    private Object receiveObject() {
        Object o = null;
        try {
             o = objIn.readObject();  // This line throws the exception
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
            Debug.error("Failed to receive object.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return o;
    }
}
```

And sending them like this:

```
private ObjectOutputStream objOut; // I did init this one
private void sendWork() {
        try {
            ParticipantWorkState pws = manager.getParticipantWorkState();
            objOut.writeObject(pws); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Debug.error("Unable to send ParticipantWorkState");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to remove as much code that is not important as i can, let me know if you need more.
The ParticipantWorkState object is not null, and implements Serializable.

PS: Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you using both PrintWriter and ObjectOutputStream on the same socket? If yes - then this might be the cause of your exception. I suggest using only ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream.

Comment: The problem is a mismatch between the classes used to write and then read the object for one of the objects that you are serializing.  One possibility is that fields were added or removed (and the serial_version_id as not changed).  Another is that the class has declared custom `readObject` and `writeObject` methods and they do not match.  Tracking this down may entail careful examination of the respective class source code; i.e. of the `ParticipantWorkState` class and its component classes.

Comment: @marcinj thanks for your suggestion. I will try to use only one type of stream, and see if that works!